# How to determine the size of an email message when using a Google Sheet Script for Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to figure out who sends me email and how large the emails are.  Determining the size is tripping me up.  I followed the directions from [this SO article](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102162/can-i-get-a-list-of-the-senders-of-all-of-the-messages-in-my-inbox) to compose a script (see below).

But how to get the size?

```
function sender_list() {
  var inbox_threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  var sender_array = [];

  //for (var i = 0; i < inbox_threads.length; i++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var message = inbox_threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var x = 0; x < message.length; x++) {
      var msg = message[x];
      var sender = msg.getFrom();
      var size = msg.getsizeEstimate(); // ???????
      sender_array.push([sender, 1, size]);
    }
  }
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(['Email Address', 'Count', 'Size']);
  sender_array.sort();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, sender_array.length, 3).setValues(sender_array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getRawContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getrawcontent) and [`Utilities#blob`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata_1) to get [blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes) and bytes and size:

```
const sizeInBytes = Utilities.newBlob(msg.getRawContent()).getBytes().length;
```

Comment: Does this include the size of the attachment as well?

Comment: @ApurvaMayank No. But You can directly use [`attachment.getSize()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#getsize)